# ParametricPlot MeshStyle bug in v10?

Tags: plotting, bugs, mesh

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.0.2.0**

---

**Original Post**

The documentation gives the following code and says "Use a *red* mesh in the x direction and a *blue* mesh in the y direction:"

```
{ParametricPlot[{u Cos[u], u Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 4 Pi}, Mesh -> 15, MeshFunctions -> {#1&, #2 &},
 MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue}, Mesh -> Automatic], ParametricPlot[{(v + u) Cos[u], (v + u) Sin[u]}, 
 {u, 0, 4 Pi}, {v, 0, 5}, MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, Blue},
 Mesh -> Automatic]}
```

but when you run the code, you'll find the meshes in second plot are both *blue*.

[image]

While in v9, this works as expected.

Is this a bug? (BTW, I'm using Windows7 32bit, Mathematica v10.0.1.0)

Comment: This does seem like a bug to me.  However in the future please wait for confirmation or consensus before adding the `bugs` tag.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard OK. I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Why is `Mesh->` occurring twice in the first one?

Comment: @KellenMyers Keen observation... I don't know. I just copied this piece of code from the documentation (the third example in `Parametric-Options-MeshStyle`). However, it won't affect the second plot if you correct or even remove the first plot.

Comment: I noticed that it has no effect .. I was wondering / hoping it might be part of what was going on, but it doesn't help. I'm perplexed because this does seem to work for other types of plots (e.g. `DensityPlot`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug is fixed in v10.0.2.0.